# how to show space between xml text node?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

i have this code in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<details>
  <detail id="bestfolio">
    <value>
        theme name:

        price:
    </value>
  </detail>
</details>
```

and this c# code for get this in c#:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    string xmlFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/static/css/xml/details.xml");

    doc.Load(xmlFilePath);

    XmlNodeList detailList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("detail");

    foreach (XmlNode node in detailList)
    {
        _value.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
            string.Format("{0}",node.Attributes["id"].InnerText
            ), string.Format("{0}",node.SelectSingleNode("value").InnerText)
            ));
    }
```

and in result for xml text i get "theme" and dont get all text,
i think when it comes to space break and dont countinue for get all text
how i can get all text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your xml with linqpad and got the correct result

[image]

there may be a problem with how you check the value

Answer (score 0):

`'&nbsp;'` insert this instead of empty space... This is a html code for space...